# How to fill hundreds of rows with the same value in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How can I fill hundreds of rows with the same value without dragging?

I know the start row is A2 and the end row is A5000, and I want to fill them with 1.

I am looking for a function that looks like

```
FILL(A2: A5000, 1)
```

Comment: Welcome! This trick can be done with `=IF(ROW(A2:A5000);<value>)` (for your example `value` is **1** or formula will be simple `=IF(ROW(A2:A5000))`). This is an array formula, finish it with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**. Keep in mind that the correct range size will only be automatically set the first time you enter the formula. If you later change A5000 to, for example, A500 or A50000, then the range will still contain the original 4999 cells, you will have to change the range size manually.

Comment: It's much easier to press **Ctrl+Shift+T** to go to the **Name Box** field, enter the desired range `A2:A5000` and press Enter - the entire range will be selected. Now press **1** and Alt+Enter - the entire selected range is filled with one value. This requires the same number of keystrokes as entering a formula, but is much more convenient.

Comment: consider to place your comment as an answer, because that's what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

- Enter the desired value or formula in the top cell (or row of cells), in your case cell A2.
- Select the range that includes the top cells and all destination cells. In your case select A2:A5000, (either enter the range in the Name Box, or select the first cell then <kbd>shift</kbd>+click the last cell).
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to fill down.